# Best way storing multiple files with various size

Tags: java

My server application stores files of different size. Database size goes up to 2-4 TB, where about 90% of all files have less than 100kb, the rest up to 2 GB.

Which would be the best way of storing these files according to following conditions:

*** The database should be portable.**

It is at the actual solution, as the index, metadata etc. is stored a SQLite3 database. Now it is a pest copying 10 million single small files so I'd prefer store small files inside archives, like 1000x 2gb files.

*** Some files are quite big, so BLOB storing may get to a performance problem**

Additionally some of the bigger(5 mb - 2gb) files may need RandomAccess reading, which won't be possible with most archive systems

*** Some transactions need to read thousands of small files at once**

..which works good with BLOB, but I'm not sure if something like a zip archive would perform well in this case. The server can in most cases put all of these files in one archive, but the objects may have to be read in random order.

*** Files stored should not be (directly) executable, but no need of encryption**

Which system would you recommend for that?

Comment: Just one quick comment, a "gzip archive" isn't a thing. gzip only compresses a single file at a time. Maybe you mean a zip archive, or a gzipped tar archive aka `.tar.gz`

Comment: edited, meant tar.gz but thats not the question :)